# Получить текст ссылки из html документа и использованием selenium.find_element_by_xpath

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, href

Нужно получить текст ссылки (не ссылку, а ее название) из html страницы, если никаких своих идентификаторов она не имеет. В распоряжении только имя класса блока:

```
<div class='unified'>
    <a href='...'>*Интересующий текст*</a>
</div>
```

Вытащить я текст хочу в скрипт на python3 с использованием модуля selenium и методом find_element_by_xpath(). Никак не выходит... даже несмотря на то, что консоль панели разработчика браузера все выводит. Скрипт выводит:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element

Comment: покажите код который вы исполняете, а то мы не экстрасенсы, что-бы без кода исправлять ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен дом селектор `div.unified a` или просто `.unified a`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".unified a")
```

Есть нюанс: на странице может быть много блоков с классом .unified и в них может быть несколько ссылок. Вы про это ничего не пишете, поэтому будем считать, что div с таким классом один и ссылка только одна.

Comment: я не знаю ситуаций, когда бы xpath не справился бы с поиском элемента, тем более, когда поиск элементарно по наличию атрибута. Я потому и хочу увидеть код автора, что-бы посмотреть где он ошибается. А переделывать с XPath на Селектор как шило на мыло, и там и там можно накосячить, а объяснить автору где же он накосячил, без его кода, как гадать на кофейной гуще